# Issue with printing generated PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

In my project I generate PDFs from HTML. The problem is these PDFs can't be printed though I they are opened and displayed correctly. Files are generated by ConvertAPI, I also tried wkhtmltopdf but it gave me the same result.

In Windows Adobe Reader 9 gave me error messages "Print is impossible" and then "No pages were selected for print" (this is translation as there isn't English localization in my Reader). After I upgraded to Adobe Reader X it started printing but only part of document and giving error message "Drawing error occurred".
Using print as images doesn't help, i just got empty sheet.

I managed to print document from Linux but it's not an option for me.

Any ideas what could be a problem here? Or at least how can i find what's actually a problem?

UPD. Most likely problems are caused by SVG in my HTML.

Comment: If you have any images or image data urls added in that pdf files, please check the file type mentioned. If it's svg, change that to png format and check.